# ¿Cómo aplicar correctamente una expresión regular para obtener el último nombre (de un archivo o carpeta) de una ruta dada e imprimirlo en Python?

Tags: python, regex, bucle-for, print

Escribí un código que crea un diccionario que almacena todas las rutas absolutas de las carpetas de la ruta actual como **llaves**, y todos sus nombres de archivo como **valores**, respectivamente. Este código solo se aplicaría a rutas que tengan carpetas que solo contengan imágenes de archivo.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import os
import re
# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}

for name in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.abspath(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        match = re.match(r'/(?:[^\\])[^\\]*$', path)
        print(match)
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

La cuestión es, que quiero que este diccionario almacene solo los **últimos nombres de carpeta** como llaves en lugar de sus rutas absolutas, así que estaba planeando usar este re `/(?:[^\\])[^\\]*$`, que se encargaría de obtener el último nombre (de un archivo o carpeta de una ruta dada) y luego agregar esos últimos nombres como llaves en el diccionario dentro del bucle for.

Quería probar el código anterior primero para ver si estaba haciendo lo que quería, pero no fue así, el valor de la variable de `match` se convirtió en `None` en cada iteración, lo que no tuvo sentido para mí, todo lo demás funciona bien.

Entonces me gustaría saber qué estoy haciendo mal aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas trabajando de más. En primer lugar, el código no es recursivo, por lo que solo explorara el primer nivel de subdirectorios.

Con el siguiente código la variable `subdir` contiene el nombre de un subdirectorio. Para formar el path completo debo unir `base_dir` con `subdir`. En otras palabras, ahí tienes lo que andabas buscando:

```
base_dir = "/home/candid/Pictures/"

for subdir in os.listdir(base_dir):
    path = f"{base_dir}{subdir}"
```

Luego que compruebas que `path` es un directorio:

```
if os.path.isdir(path):
```

Puedes entrar y listarlo:

```
    print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
    list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
    print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
```

y almacenar el resultado bajo la llave deseada:

```
    the_dictionary_list[subdir] = list_of_file_contents
```

#### Demo

El código completo:

```
import os

the_dictionary_list = {}
base_dir = "/home/candid/Pictures/Wallpapers/"

for subdir in os.listdir(base_dir):
    path = f"{base_dir}{subdir}"
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[subdir] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
for subdir in the_dictionary_list:
    print(subdir)
    for archivo in the_dictionary_list[subdir]:
        print("    ", archivo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basada en la respuesta de @candid-moe, decidí replantear el código de arriba para el caso de querer aplicarlo sólo en el directorio actual (en el que se encontraría el programa).

```
import os
# Main method

the_dictionary_list = {}

for subdir in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(subdir):
        path = os.path.abspath(subdir)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[subdir] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\033[1;37;40mThe dictionary list:\033[0m')
for subdir in the_dictionary_list:
    print('\u001b[43m'+subdir+'\033[0m')
    for archivo in the_dictionary_list[subdir]:
        print("    ", archivo)
print('\n')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

Esto sería útil en caso de que el usuario quiera poner correr el programa con doble click en una ubicación concreta (*mi caso personal*).

Answer (score 1):

También puedes simplemente usar `os.path.basename(dir...)`

```py
import os
import re
# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}

for name in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')

        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

de tal forma que la salida es (según las carpetas que he agregado manualmente):

```
n1
['jaja.jpg', 'jojo.jpg']


n2
['im.jpg']


the_dictionary_list:
{'n1': ['jaja.jpg', 'jojo.jpg'], 'n2': ['im.jpg']}
```